# /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file assimp2json: Is a directory

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, cmake, assimp

Building assimp works fine after a bit of tinkering, but the Readme.md is pretty unclear about building assimp2json.
When building from github dot com/assimp/assimp2json, the error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file assimp2json: Is a directory" is produced.
When searching the web for this problem, I found that with other software it was fine to delete the conflicting directory, but that is not the case here, the contents are required.
Also renaming the dir on the filesystem and the references to the dir in the CMakeLists.txt, did not work, as it resulted in the output file name being changed to that of the new dir name.
In the make manual I can not find an option to change the output path. And after searching the web some more I feel stuck.

Less sussinct output around the error: "

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libassimp.so
[ 97%] Built target assimp
Scanning dependencies of target assimp2json
[ 98%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/assimp2json/main.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/assimp2json/json_exporter.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building C object CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/assimp2json/cencode.c.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/assimp2json/mesh_splitter.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable assimp2json
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file assimp2json: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/build.make:162: recipe for target 'assimp2json' failed
make[2]: *** [assimp2json] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

".

Commands I use to build: "

```
git clone https://github.com/assimp/assimp2json
cd assimp2json
git submodule init
git submodule update
cmake CMakeLists.txt
make
```

".

Also tried "cmake CMakeLists.txt -G 'Unix Makefiles'" as stated in github dot com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/INSTALL, to no avail.

As github dot com/assimp/assimp2json is forked from github dot com/acgessler/assimp2json which has more recent commits (2013 vs. 2015), I also tried building that with the same commands.
And changed line 34 of assimp/cmake-modules/AddGTest.cmake from "GIT_REPOSITORY chromium.googlesource dot com/external/googletest" to "GIT_REPOSITORY github dot com/google/googletest/".

This makes a bit of progress, but not enough: "

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libassimp.so
[ 80%] Built target assimp
Scanning dependencies of target assimp2json
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/assimp2json/main.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/assimp2json/json_exporter.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building C object CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/assimp2json/cencode.c.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/assimp2json.dir/assimp2json/mesh_splitter.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable bin/assimp2json
[ 82%] Built target assimp2json
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
[ 82%] Creating directories for 'gtest'
[ 83%] Performing download step (git clone) for 'gtest'
-- gtest download command succeeded.  See also /opt/assimp2json/assimp/test/gtest/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-download-*.log

[ 84%] No patch step for 'gtest'
[ 84%] Performing update step for 'gtest'
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
[ 84%] Performing configure step for 'gtest'
-- gtest configure command succeeded.  See also /opt/assimp2json/assimp/test/gtest/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-configure-*.log

[ 85%] Performing build step for 'gtest'
-- gtest build command succeeded.  See also /opt/assimp2json/assimp/test/gtest/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-build-*.log

[ 86%] No install step for 'gtest'
[ 86%] Completed 'gtest'
[ 86%] Built target gtest
Scanning dependencies of target unit
[ 86%] Building C object assimp/test/CMakeFiles/unit.dir/unit/CCompilerTest.c.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object assimp/test/CMakeFiles/unit.dir/unit/Main.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/assimp2json/assimp/test/unit/Main.cpp:1:0:
/opt/assimp2json/assimp/test/unit/UnitTestPCH.h:11:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
assimp/test/CMakeFiles/unit.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'assimp/test/CMakeFiles/unit.dir/unit/Main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [assimp/test/CMakeFiles/unit.dir/unit/Main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:250: recipe for target 'assimp/test/CMakeFiles/unit.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [assimp/test/CMakeFiles/unit.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

".

Are other people able to build this and willing to share the trick? Or are others failing to and should I look at other software? Assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

assimp2json : Builds OK here with the right commands .... [100%] Built target assimp2json

```
git clone https://github.com/assimp/assimp2json.git
cd assimp2json/
git submodule init
git submodule update
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ../
make
```

I.e. the most "cmake builds" will require a build/ folder.
And : May be you are using a too late g++ for the three year old code.  Suggest : `CXX=g++-4.9 cmake ../` ... Any further issues ? Then please update your post with your OS name and version.